# Solving $\cosh{x}+\cos{x}=0$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I have the following equation:

> $$\cosh{x}+\cos{x}=0$$

My solution is as follows:

$$\cos{ix}+\cos{x}=0$$

$$\cos{ix}=-\cos{x}$$

$$\cos{ix}=\cos{(x+(2k+1)\pi)},  k\in\mathbb{N}$$

$$ix=x+(2k+1)\pi$$

$$x(-1+i)=(2k+1)\pi$$

$$x=\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{(-1+i)}=-\frac{1}{2}(1+i)(2k+1)\pi$$

Is this the correct procedure and is this all solutions?

Comment: You're making the assumption that cosine doesn't vanish at any nonreal argument.

Comment: Are there nonreal zeros for $\cos$? I don't think so since that would imply $e^{2iz}=1$ has nonreal solutions but if the exponent was not purely imaginary then the absolute value would not be 1.

Comment: @Tob, you're right, I just thought OP should point that out in the write-up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\cosh x+\cos x=0$$ $$e^x+e^{-x}+e^{ix}+e^{-ix}=0$$ $$(e^{(1+i)x/2}+e^{-(1+i)x/2})(e^{(1-i)x/2}+e^{-(1-i)x/2})=0$$ $$e^{(1+i)x/2}+e^{-(1+i)x/2}=0{\rm\quad or\quad}e^{(1-i)x/2}+e^{-(1-i)x/2}=0$$ $$e^{(1+i)x}=-1{\rm\quad or\quad}e^{(1-i)x}=-1$$ and so on, is another way to get there.